# How Core.JS Code be undone without altering main files?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
function USScroll(options) {
        var defaults = {
            attachOnInit: '.menu-item a[href*="#"], .menu-item[href*="#"], a.w-btn[href*="#"], .w-iconbox a[href*="#"], .w-image a[href*="#"], .w-img a[href*="#"], .w-text a[href*="#"], ' + '.vc_icon_element a[href*="#"], .vc_custom_heading a[href*="#"], a.w-grid-item-anchor[href*="#"], .w-toplink, ' + '.w-blogpost-meta-comments a[href*="#"], .w-comments-title a[href*="#"], .w-comments-item-date, a.smooth-scroll[href*="#"]',
            buttonActiveClass: 'active',
            menuItemActiveClass: 'current-menu-item',
            menuItemAncestorActiveClass: 'current-menu-ancestor',
            animationDuration: $us.canvasOptions.scrollDuration,
            animationEasing: 'easeInOutExpo'
        };
```

This is the code in th core.js | The above code is creating issue I have a modal box that should be clicked on clicking an anchor tag, but instead of rendering the click behavior and opening the modal box it scrolls to the destination of #anchors and that is taking away the target. How should I fix this?

I wanted to do it in such a way that w/o touching the core file of core.js.

I am a new member please bear with me and let me know if I can provide some extra information.

Answer (score 0):

It's not something you'd fix in USScroll, it's something you'd fix in the code responding to the anchor click to show (hide? I can't tell from your question) the modal. That code should call `preventDefault()` on the event object it receives. (You may well also want to call `stopPropagation()` on it, if there's a click handler on an ancestor element that's getting triggered inappropriately.)

Comment: Hello sir, the code is [here](https://blnk.in/9ntQcg) In the footer you will see `Contact Pop up` that is clickable, but not clicking. However, if you open that in the new window than modal pop up. Also, this is WordPress.